# If $g(x)= (x^2 +2x+3)f(x)$ and $f(0)=5$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-5}x =4$, then what is $g'(0)$?

Tags: calculus

I first differentiated $g(x)$ using the product rule. Calculated $f'(0)$ using the given limit and substituted to get $g'(0)= 22$, but the answer is given to be $14$. Where am I wrong?

[This is the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtRz2.jpg) I can't figure it out.

Comment: I am with you $g'(0) = 2f(0) + 3f'(0) = 22$

Answer (score 1):

Following your link:

$g'(0) =\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {(x^2+2x + 2)f(x) - 3f(0)}{x}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to 0} x + 2\color{red}{f(x)} + \frac { 3(f(x) - f(0))}{x}\\
$

And that $f(x)$ is missing in your linked solution.  If you account for that you get 22.

Answer (score 1):

From scratch:

Differentiate $g(x)$: $g'(x) = (x^2 + 2x + 3) f'(x) + (2x + 2) f(x)$

Try to find $g'(0)$: $g'(0) = 3 f'(0) + 2 f(0) = 10 + 3 f'(0)$

To find $f'(0)$ use the $x \to a$ limit definition: $f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$.

Find $f'(0)$ with this definition: $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - 5}{x}$ which is given to be $4 \implies f'(0) = 4$; thus, $g'(0) = 10 + 12 = 22$.

As Doug M has already pointed out, the solution provided [incorrectly distributes the $f(x)$ term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBjiO.png) here. The difference between $2$ and $2 f(0) = 10$ happens to be $22 - 14 = 8$.